# How come the <xsl:template match="//step[@ID='xxx']"> information displays at the top of my page?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am using an xsl file to read XML to create a page. At the top of my page I have:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//step[@ID='CCRI001']">

<html>
<head>
<title>Help - <xsl:value-of select="infoItems"/></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />

<script language="JavaScript" for="window" event="onload">
function resizeWindow()
{
top.resizeTo(500,300)
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p><b>Functional Owner: </b><xsl:value-of select="title" /></p>
<p><b>Number of Items: </b><xsl:value-of select="infoItems" /></p>
<p><b>Point 1: </b><xsl:value-of select="information1" /></p>
<p><b>Point 2: </b><xsl:value-of select="information2" /></p>
</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <alerts>
        <step ID="CCRA001">
            <title>ho</title>
            <infoItems>4</infoItems>
            <information1>z</information1>
            <information2>y</information2>
            <information3>x</information3>
            <information4>w</information4>
        </step>
        <step ID="CCRI001">
            <title>hi</title>
            <infoItems>4</infoItems>
            <information1>a</information1>
            <information2>b</information2>
            <information3>c</information3>
            <information4>d</information4>
        </step>
    </alerts>
</xml>
```

At the top of my page when I open the HTML, I see the values of the **xsl:template match="//step[@ID='CCRI001']"** (Hi 4 a b c d) that are right from the XML and I am not sure why it is showing up there.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, including an XML and a small, but complete XSLT - see: [mcve].

Comment: Hi. I added more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the result of the [build-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) being applied to the nodes for which you have no matching template (that is mainly the 1st `step` and its descendants).

Try instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/xml">
<html>
<head>
<title>Help - <xsl:value-of select="infoItems"/></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" for="window" event="onload">
function resizeWindow()
{
top.resizeTo(500,300)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates select="alerts/step[@ID='CCRI001']"/>
</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="step">
<p><b>Functional Owner: </b><xsl:value-of select="title" /></p>
<p><b>Number of Items: </b><xsl:value-of select="infoItems" /></p>
<p><b>Point 1: </b><xsl:value-of select="information1" /></p>
<p><b>Point 2: </b><xsl:value-of select="information2" /></p>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that starting a match pattern with `//` is meaningless.

Comment: thanks for your help. It was perfect and it working out very well. Thanks.